# How to get the printout from the results of a subprocess.run() function to appear the same as seen in a terminal?

Tags: python, printing, character-encoding, subprocess, ubuntu-18.04

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['pkexec', 'apt', 'update'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout)
```

`print(result.stdout)` returned a very long string. See below.

`pprint.pprint(result.stdout)` returned the same content as a block of sentences. See below.

I would like the print out of `result.stdout` to be similar to the terminal print out when executing `sudo apt update`. How can I achieve it with python 3.6 found in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: What do you get from `print(result.stdout.decode())`? Is that what you expect or is it still a lot of text?

Comment: @JohanL Thanks. It worked. Can you put it up as an answer so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a block of "text" is that the output is not an actual `string` (which is utf-8 encoded in Python 3) but a `bytes` object. This is seen from the `b` being written in front of the text. In order to turn a `bytes` object into a `string` it needs to be "decoded."

To decode the `bytes` object the `text.decode()` method is used, for the particular string in this question that turns into

```
 print(result.stdout.decode())
```

The `bytes` object can be of any coding, therefore the `.decode()` call accepts a parameter which tells which coding that is supposed to be decoded. The most common one is utf-8 so if no parameter is given, this is assumed. However, specifically on Windows systems, also other codings exists (e.g. "latin1"). To decode a "latin1" `bytes`object the call would thus look like

```
print(text.decode("latin1"))
```

The opposite operation, which encodes a `string` to a `bytes` object is also available. Logically enough it is called `.encode()` and is typically used in protocols that stream the data to another destination (e.g. over the Internet or to disc). Also this call accepts code argument, that allows the text to be encoded as e.g. "latin1" even though the default is "utf-8".